# spring data arangodb many to many mapping

Tags: spring-data, arangodb

I am interested in data modeling in ArangoDB.

I am reading the white paper "Switching from Relational Databases to ArangoDB", and I wonder how the many to many relationship on page 18 of the paper is done in Spring Data ArangoDB?

[image: many to many relationship recommended in arangodb]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `@Ref` annotation in the [docs](https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data/blob/master/docs/Drivers/SpringData/Reference/README.md#reference) of arangodb-spring-data. This annotations works for single beans and collections/lists of beans.

```
public class Genre {
  @Id
  private String id;
}

public class Album {
  @Id
  private String id;

  @Ref
  private Collection<Genre> genres;
}
```

There is also a very extensive [demo](https://arangodb.com/tutorials/spring-data/) for ArangoDB Spring Data. If you are new to the topic you should definitely take a look into it.

Comment: Thanks @mpv1989. l am not new to spring & spring data, but just compare spring-data-arangodb to spring-data-jpa when doing data modeling. Question (2) : Is this means that the method using **Ref** is not specify to arangodb and can be use in mongdb or any other document databases ? If the answer is yes, any performance different using **Ref** compare to other document databases ? Question (3) : How different is the AQL query of **Ref style** compare to **graph style**?

Comment: Question 2: The `Ref` annotation in arangodb-spring-data works the same as i.e. the `DBRef` annotation in spring-data for monogdb. It saves the document handle (Genre) in the document (Album). In ArangoDB you have the opportunity to perform a join within AQL for this document handle.

Question 3: With `Ref` you perform a simple join:
`FOR a IN Album
     FOR g IN Genre
          RETURN g`

When using a graph model you perform a graph traversal in AQL. https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/AQL/Graphs/TraversalsExplained.html